# Removing nongreyscale colored components from document image

Tags: numpy, rgb, scikit-image

I need to prepare document image for its further recognising. There is a strict rule in my country that documents have to be written with black or grey colored fonts. Signatures and stamps also have to be blue colored. So in current step I need to remove stamps and signatures by removing non-grey scale colored elements. This is example of document's fragment: [image: example of document's fragment which will be analysed]
I have written code to convert into gray scale a gray-scaled components and non-grey-scaled components separately:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgba2rgb, rgb2grey, colorconv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def separate_color_regions(im):
    if im.shape[-1]==4:
        im=rgba2rgb(im)
    #representin each color chanel as float in range [0, 1.]
    im=colorconv._prepare_colorarray(im)

    #because we wont decompose black color instead of white
    im=1.-im

    #calculate gray component using the formula: grey=cos_a*|color|*(1, 1, 1)/sqrt(3), 
    #according to scalar multiplication formula cos_a*|color|=color*(1, 1, 1)/sqrt(3)
    #here sqrt(3) added since |(1, 1, 1)|=sqrt(3)
    gray=(im[..., 0]+im[..., 1]+im[..., 2])/3
    proj=im.copy()
    for i in range(3):
        proj[..., i]-=gray
    def norm(inp):
        """
        convert each color vector to its l2 norm
        """
        t=inp*inp
        return np.sqrt(np.sum(t, -1))
    def mask_nan(inp):
        where_are_NaNs = np.isnan(inp)
        inp[where_are_NaNs] = 0.
        return inp
    return 1.-mask_nan(norm(proj)/norm(im)), 1.-mask_nan((3.**0.5)*gray/norm(im))
im=io.imread('stamps.png')
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3)
ax1.imshow(im)
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('Original image')
nongray, gray=separate_color_regions(im)
ax2.imshow(nongray, cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='none')
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.set_title('Non-grey_components filter')
ax3.imshow(gray, cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='none')
ax3.axis('off')
ax3.set_title('Grey component filter')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And here is results of it's performance:
[image: result of performance of my code]
You see that it only can highlight non-grayscale objects, but unable to separete gray-scale objects from ones and bring many noise to image. Please advise me if there is a better solution for my case.

Comment: Instead of setting a threshold manually, you could set a threshold on the blue channel of the image. In this case it would be applicable to any kind of documents available in your country. If you go by the manual method it might fail in some occasions where a different type of ink is used.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it with manually seted threshold:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgba2rgb, rgb2grey, colorconv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def separate_color_regions(im):
    if im.shape[-1]==4:
        im=rgba2rgb(im)
    #representin each color chanel as float in range [0, 1.]
    im=colorconv._prepare_colorarray(im)

    #because we wont decompose black color instead of white
    im=1.-im

    #calculate gray component using the formula: grey=cos_a*|color|*(1, 1, 1)/sqrt(3), 
    #according to scalar multiplication formula cos_a*|color|=color*(1, 1, 1)/sqrt(3)
    #here sqrt(3) added since |(1, 1, 1)|=sqrt(3)
    gray=(im[..., 0]+im[..., 1]+im[..., 2])/3
    proj=im.copy()
    for i in range(3):
        proj[..., i]-=gray
    def norm(inp):
        """
        convert each color vector to its l2 norm
        """
        t=inp*inp
        return np.sqrt(np.sum(t, -1))
    def mask_nan(inp):
        where_are_NaNs = np.isnan(inp)
        inp[where_are_NaNs] = 0.
        return inp
    return 1.-mask_nan(norm(proj)/norm(im)), 1.-mask_nan((3.**0.5)*gray/norm(im))
im=io.imread('stamps.png')
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3)
ax1.imshow(im)
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('Original image')
nongray, gray=separate_color_regions(im)
ax2.imshow(nongray, cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='none')
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.set_title('Non-grey_components filter')
mask=np.vectorize(lambda d: 0. if d>0.1 else 1.)
ax3.imshow(1.-(1.-rgb2grey(im))*mask(1.-nongray), cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='none')
ax3.axis('off')
ax3.set_title('Grey component filter')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]